# getJSON to console.log() to output json structure

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code for getting json data:

```
$.getJSON( "assessments", function( assessments ) {
    console.log(assessments);
        });
```

I am perfectly getting all the data but the console has output as

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I want to output the values in JSON structure like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "person": {
        "personId": "person1",
        "firstName": "Pactric"
    },
    "manager": {
        "managerId": "manager1"
    },
    "state": {
        "stateId": 1,
        "description": null
    },
    "comments": null
}
]
```

How to console.log() for this data to display exactly as above's JSON structure?
I am using $.getJSON NOT $.ajax for this application.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

try with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(assessments));
```

Comment: it does not allow me for some time to close the answer, it now says I can not close your answer till 10 minutes. I will close it :-)

Answer (score 36):

Stringify the JSON with indentation like so :

```
$.getJSON( "assessments", function( assessments ) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(assessments, undefined, 2))
});
```

`JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])` where space is the indent. [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: This should be the answer... It outputs the JSON in some awesome "verbose" mode. Thanks!

Comment: @derekmx271 - thanks, the question was after all *"display exactly as above's JSON structure"*, and this does that, it adds the spaces and newlines and outputs the JSON in a neat readable format.

Comment: MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @s.matthew.english the $ replaced the older jQuery. In the past you'd have to write "jQuery.getJSON()" Where now you can just type "$.getJSON()". I suppose it could be considered a namespace, but it also enhances what jQuery is popular for.... brevity.