# VueJS Resource plugin example

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am attempting to display a JSON response from PHP. I was pointed in the direction of the VueJS resource plugin. Unfortunately, the examples it gives are vague at best.

Is anyone able to provide a simple example of how to display the return JSON object in a list?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I have the json response that is produced from JSON_ENCODE with php.  I need to know how to get and display it with vue.js.   I have the vuejs resource plugin but I'm not sure how to get everything to work.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I thought then. I never used vue.js but you can log the json in the javascript console with console.log(), see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500836/getjson-to-console-log-to-output-json-structure

Comment: If you wanna display the JSON as it is, like string, i.e. "[....]", then TecBeast's answer is right. If you wanna iterate thru that JSON and render data i.e. to a table, then Samuel's answer is right.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<table id="list-items">
    <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#list-items',
    data: {
        items: []
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.items = this.getItems();
    },
    methods: {
        getItems: function() {
            this.$http.get('items.php', function(data){
                this.items = data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

items.php must return a JSON encoded array like this:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'foo'},{id: 2, name: 'bar'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue 1.0.1 you can use `v-for` instead of `v-repeat`  like this:

```
<table id="list-items">
  <tr v-for="item in items">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
{{ $data | json }}
```