# how to get the entire content of a JSON file in the console.log

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have kind of a weird question.

My JSON looks like this:

```
var content = '{"content":[' +

'{"value1": "0", "value2": "0", "value3": "20", "value4": "40", "value5": "string" },' +

...

'{"value1": "0", "value2": "0", "value3": "20", "value4": "40", "value5": "string" }]}';
```

I am wondering how to get the content of a JSON file "as it is" displayed in the `console.log();` ? I want the exact JSON file.

When I do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(content);
  console.log(obj);
```

or

```
var obj = JSON.parse(content);
  console.log(obj.content);
```

I only get this

> [object Object]

Is there something like `obj.all()` or something?

Comment: It is Chrome and Firefox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500836/getjson-to-console-log-to-output-json-structure

Comment: To see the `json` as it is, do not parse it!

Comment: Stringify your output `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.content));`

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/32b974b0-1839-4f72-83ba-b5495bb15a06/f4adc9ac783b35c1)

Comment: I do not have that issue....So what are you actually doing?

Comment: works for me, the stringify solution, which answer should I accept now? I think Sebass was the fastest. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've also found the copy() command from the console helpful to extract that object and bring it somewhere else:  `> copy(content)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't parse the JSON to get it logged.

A

> JSON

is a string.

So do only

```
console.log(content);
```

Comment: btw: "Rayon Dabre" was some seconds earlier in the comment above